How to bind a color from a ViewModel to each TreeView node?
Do I need to bind a color from the ViewModel to each node in the TreeView?
I tried using styles, but I was able to set the color for all nodes, but not for each one specifically. How can I do this?
<TreeView Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding LeftTreeNodes}">
    <!--<TreeView.Styles>
        <Style Selector="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Styles>-->
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </TreeDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

  internal class TreeNodeViewModel : ViewModel
  {  
        private Color nodeColor = Colors.White;
        private string text;
        
        public TreeNodeViewModel(string text, Color nodeColor, string icon)
        {
            this.nodeColor = nodeColor;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public string Text => text;

        public Color Color => nodeColor;

        public ObservableCollection<TreeNodeViewModel> Children { get; set; } = [];
    }


Have view model that represents a tree node, and store color in that view model instance.
public class TreeNodeViewModel
{
   // code skipped

   public Color NodeColor { get; set; }

   // code skipped
}

Then bind NodeColor property from your XAML code.

The Background property is of type Brush. In order to bind it to a view model property of type Color, you could declare a Style Setter like this:
<Style Selector="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

